# MonoTouch: Create iOS AppStore-Version from command line

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, xamarin, mdtool

I want to build my ios-apps Appstore-ready directly from the command line with the mdtool from MonoTouch (Xamarin) so that Jenkins can kick in and produce the uploadable package right away.

I use the following command:

```
'/Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool' -v build '--configuration:AppStore|iPhone' MyAppProject.csproj
```

Now, the build runs, uses my AppStore Provisioning Profile and creates the files in my *bin/iPhone/AppStore* - folder.

Now, according to the [documentation of Xamarin](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution_overview), I should zip the created app-file in the *bin/iPhone/AppStore* and select it in xCode Application Loader like shown in the screenshot:

[image]

But the Application Loader shows every file grayed out, so there is no chance to continue.

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

What if you rename the .zip extension to .ipa?

Comment: The "Ios" file at the top without visible extension is actually the Ios.app, seems like the extension is hidden in the finder. The Ios.app.zip is just that Ios.app in a zip archive. The Ios.app.zip.ipa is the Ios.app.zip renamed to ipa. Am I zipping the correct files?

Comment: I didn't mean rename it to AppName.zip.ipa, I meant rename it to AppName.ipa. Not sure if that'll make a difference.

Comment: zip -r AppName.zip AppName.app; mv AppName.zip AppName.ipa

Comment: Again, no change. If I let Xamarin Studio do the zipping for me via "Project -> Zip App Bundle", it is also executing *zip -r -y "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/projectname/workspace/build/ios/Ios.zip" "Ios.app"* - so it only contains the .app

Comment: Nope, exactly the same with your zip command *zip -r AppName.zip AppName.app; mv AppName.zip AppName.ipa* or the execution directly from Xamarin Studio. The Application Loader doesn't want to accept anything... :(

Comment: Is it possible that I have to create the app first at iTunes connect?

Comment: You probably do need to do that, but I'd be surprised if that made the file selectable in the file selector window :-\

Comment: Okay, I'll get back to this post if we are right before releasing the app. Thank you so far - I'll give you an upvote by now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not choose "Open package" but "Deliver Your App".

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the xcrun ("XCode Run") command line tool to with the "PackageApplication" argument to package an ".app" into an ".ipa" and optionally specify a signing identity and provisioning profile at the same time.

Something like:

```
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "Ios.app" -o "Ios.ipa" --sign "[DEVELOPER_NAME]" --embed "[PROVISONING_PROFILE]”
```

More info on xcrun here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcrun.1.html